# What do I need to know to make my website work on mobile browsers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-mobile, cell

I am using ASP.NET 3.5 with Visual Studio 2008. I have a few questions surrounding my website and mobile users.

1. Will my website be displayed correctly on a mobile?
2. What items will not work on a mobile (I know flash can be a problem?)
3. What advice can you give me for my website to work 100% on a mobile?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See these links

[7 usability guidelines for websites on mobile devices](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/web-usability/mobile-guidelines.shtml)

[Designing Web Sites for the Internet Explorer for Pocket PC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838316.aspx)

[Make Your Web Applications Support Pocket PC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838560.aspx)

[W3C recommendations for Mobile websites](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/CR-mobile-bp-20060627/)

Bye

Answer (score 0):

head:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ContentType="application/xhtml+xml"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
```

Page must be 100% valid: use `&amp;` instead of `&`, and `<br/>` instead of `<br>` and so on.
Do not use external css files, it must be inline.
Do not use javascript.

Comment: Erm, maybe if your mobile is from the last century or something. I'm not sure it's worth targeting them.

Comment: Just so to be clear: your markup should of course always be well formed, even if you're not targeting mobile. External CSS and JavaScript work fairly well on anything worth using.

Answer (score 0):

to do a mobil website you have to watc out for:

- scaling of course, make sure everything fit and every text is readeble.
- Flash is a problem :s
- Dont forget to try on multi mobil borswer (IE,OPERA,....)
- Do not put big images or else the load would be slow and will unscale everything.
- You can check out [Microsoft best practices for mobil dev](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/default.aspx)
- If your website has textbox use auto implementation, for some device is painfull to write in a mobil website

i will put some more later, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

1- No it will not.

2- that's depend on the version of OS on mobile

3- you have to build your mobile application from the beginning by using **mobile controls** and **Mobile web form** (A Form for mobile Web Applications) instead of web form.

all of this controls are under this namespace:

```
using System.Web.UI.MobileControls;
```

That's will make your application to work on more than 200 types of mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

One of [Scott Hanselman's podcasts](http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx) talked about the [Mobile Device Browser File for ASP.Net](http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=172). This is a file that contains feature information about loads of different mobile devices and browsers. For example, you can check if a mobile device connecting to your site has support for cookies, or find out its screen size, etc.

I've never done any mobile development, but this looks as if it could be very useful.

This is on CodePlex here: http://mdbf.codeplex.com/

Comment: Due to the organizational restructuring of the team that developed and supported the Mobile Device Browser file, we will no longer have the resources to support and update this CodePlex project. The team will be providing two more releases – one on the 27th July 2010 and the final release on the 24th August 2010.