# What do I need to know to make my website work on mobile devices nowadays?

Tags: android, iphone, django, web-applications, mobile

This question is based on [What do I need to know to make my website work on mobile browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320764/what-do-i-need-to-know-to-make-my-website-work-on-mobile-browsers) which was posted in 2009 with some old websites and specific Microsoft stuff

I make web-apps mostly in Django and it doesn't seem to work very well in Android/Iphone/other mobile devices.

There are some apps like django-mobile (https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-mobile) that offers you the possiblity of making different sites depending on the flavor of the device. The problem is that we almost have to make 3 websites if we want to use it in Android, Iphone and PCs.

There are some W3C recommendations (http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/CR-mobile-bp-20060627/) from 2006, with I think is obsolete because 6 years made the internet and the devices completelly different.

Any contributions concerning that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know (correct me if im wrong) Django is a Python framework, so it runs server-side. That should not effect anything running on the phone. All smart phones will be able to run HTML/CSS and JavaScript/jQuery.

If you are talking about how the page is displayed on such a small screen there are several options:

1. Have a responsive design that adapts to the device's screen size. Have a look at [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/).
2. Have a separate mobile site and something that will detect a mobile/tablet device and forward it to the mobile site running on a subdomain like `mobile.mysite.com`.
3. Have a non-responsive site and use the [`viewport` meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).
4. Another option is to use css media queries, which allow you to set conditional css depending on the screen or browser dimensions like this :

   ```
   @media only screen 
   and (min-width : 325px) 
   and (max-width : 500px) {
   /*CONDITION CSS*/
   }
   ```

The nice thing about media queries is that you can get really detailed in theory you could have a media queries for 100's of devices specifying specific css for both the devices landscape and portrait mode.

[Here's](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2012/08/22/separate-mobile-responsive-website-presidential-smackdown/) quite an interesting article about the Romney versus Obamas campaign and how each party has chosen to develop their mobile sites differently.

Comment: +1. Was just about to post Twitter Bootstrap as an example of the increasingly popular method of using fluid layouts with `@media` queries.